# how to find the density function of 2D random variable?

Tags: probability, random-variables

Let $(X,Y)$ be $2$ dimensional random variable with uniform distribution  on the domain $$D = \left\{\left.(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2 \ \right| \ x\geq0 \ , \ y\geq0 \ , \ x+y\leq1 \right\}$$ for
$y\in(0,1)$ find the density function $f_{X|Y}(x|y)$

My main problem is that I don't understand how to write $f_{X,Y}(x,y)$ I understand how does it look in one dimensional but when it became 2 or higher I dont understand how to write an expression for it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume familiarity with [indicator functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indicator_function) & [Iverson brackets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iverson_bracket). The locus $\{x|(x,\,y)\in D\}$ is the line segment $[0,\,1-y]\times\{y\}$, so $f_{X|Y}(x|y)=\frac{1}{1-y}1_{[0,\,1-y]}(x)$. Since $D$ is a triangle of area $\tfrac12$, $f_{X,\,Y}(x,\,y)=2[(x,\,y)\in D]$.